# jSON: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jsonp

I know I am not the first one to get this error and there are so many other posts for this error on Stack Overflow. However, I couldn't find the solution and hence, writing this question.

I am quite fresher and have recently started learning JSON, jQuery, JavaScript with HTML5. So, I wanted to do some hands on with the very basic example as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
debugger;
</script>
<title>Doc Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="rssFeed">News Loadin...</p>
<script>
debugger;
var yQuery = 'http://news.google.com/news?geo=02138&output=rss';
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent("select * from xml where url='" + yQuery + "'") + '&format=json&callback=?';
debugger;
(function(){
    debugger;
    $.getJSON(yql)
    debugger;
     .done(function(data){
        debugger;
        $.each(data.query.results.item, function(i,item){
            alert(item.link);
        });
     });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML file is on my local machine and I am testing it in the Chrome browser. The only thing I see in my browser is 'News Loadin...' text. I do not get any alert (from the alert(item.link);).

I tried to debug this code in Chrome (F12) and also put few 'debuggers' in the code. In the debug window, I see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` error at the line `.done(function(data)`

For the URL, I have tried both options as suggested on other answers on Stack Over flow for the same error.

- callback=?
- callback=cbfunc

The yql will have the following value:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Fgeo%3D02138%26output%3Drss'&format=json&callback=cbfunc
```

If I put the `yql` with `'cbfunc'` in the browser URL, I get the JSON, if I put `'?'` I get error.
However, none of them works when I load the HTML and I get the same error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` for both.

Another issue I have noticed is, whenever I open this file in Chrome, the debugger only stops at the first `debugger` I have in the `<script>` under `<head>` element. It does not stop at any of the `debugger` statements in the `<body>.` This happens even if I put the breakpoint (by selecting the row number) in Chrome dev tools. It just wouldn't stop in the `<body>` element.

I'm pretty new to this stuff, so please pardon my any dumb mistake here.

Regards,
Rumit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
$.getJSON(yql)
    debugger; // <<== remove this line
        .done(function(data){
```

`.done()` is called on `$.getJSON(yql)`, your `debugger` is breaking syntax

Comment: You're awesome man! My mistake was that, I put my very first debugger on THAT line and it didn't work. So, later added few more and ended up going in the wrong direction. Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: @rumitpatel, glab to help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'debugger;' on the line before .done(..).
The .done(..) is called on the object returned from $.getJSON(yql)...